# How to get the COBRA toolbox working with proper SBML support under MATLAB in linux (such as Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: linux, matlab, io, bioinformatics, sbml

Consider these 4 pieces of software:

1. COBRA 2.05
2. LibSBML 5.10
3. MATLAB R2013a (Also known as 8.1, 64-bit; MATLAB no longer supports 32-bit Linux anyway)
4. A 64-bit Linux OS (such as Ubuntu 14.04 or the latest Mint but not restricted to them)

**Intro**

The COBRA toolbox is an optimization suite that runs on top of MATLAB aimed at the development of MATLAB code for metabolic network modelling. Such a "network" is a system of equations that can have a very large number of equations and variables (such as thousands). Therefore, routines to read and write those large models according to some format specification are a must-have, and COBRA uses the standard SBML for that.

**Problem**

Unlike the Windows versions, the Linux binary packages do not integrate well out-of-the-box: to begin with, the pre-compiled Linux binary of libSBML (open-source) available for download does not come with MATLAB support. If one tries to use the pre-compiled libSBML, COBRA won't find the "MATLAB bindings" and therefore won't be able to, for example, read and write SBML XML files from the disk in a m-script.

**The question**

What needs to be done to make COBRA 2.05 running on top of MATLAB R2013a under Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 or the latest Mint, but this is not likely distro-specific) able to read and write SBML XML files? In other words, what needs to be done system-wide to make COBRA pass its own `testSBML` test?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it working and what I could learn from all the hassle regarding how my Linux box works. I hope I am not forgetting/missing/mistaking anything.

## 1. MATLAB

### 1.1. Install MATLAB

Install it in its default location (you will need root access for this), don't be stubborn like I tried to be. Why:

#### 1.1.1. Integration

It is very likely you will want to install some other software that uses the MATLAB framework at some point, and in the real world software doesn't always find other software even if you know how to tell it where to look for.

#### 1.1.2. Make your life easier

Even though it seems like a good idea to install a big software in a place where you have lots of available space and that you can use in multiple machines (specially in Linux, which doesn't have that abomination called Registry, and has symbolic links), that would only perhaps be a good idea - apart from item ***1.1.1*** - if that place is a partition with a Linux filesystem, since at some point, some executable/script will need execution permission, and mounting the entire partition with execution permission for all its files is rather unsafe. Therefore, do not put MATLAB in an NTFS partition of an external HD; perhaps creating a Linux partition in the external HD just for Linux-specific stuff could work for this matter, but how much hassle is that?

### 1.2. Setup MATLAB so people and other software can launch it

Even though I have seen somewhere that the MATLAB installer eventually shows an option to create symbolic links in the system path for convenience, it didn't in my case. But that is OK, since I would have to replace the symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/matlab` by the following shell-script (same path, same filename) anyway:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    exec /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab $*
```

OBS: That `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is needed for MATLAB to find SBML bindings later and to be able to use them. Also, if you install some third-party solver such as TOMLAB, you will most likely need to add some more paths in this little launcher script.
OBS 2: In my case, the installation script didn't automatically create any launchers or shortcuts, but I have found an iconless and extension-less `Matlab 8.01` file and a matlab icon as a png file, and that first file was a template `.desktop` file that I could edit to fit my needs and put in `/usr/share/applications` so the Unity Dash would find it. The contents of this `Matlab.desktop` file are:

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Icon=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/Matlab.png
    Name=Matlab 8.01
    Comment="Start Matlab 8.01"
    Exec=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/matlab -desktop
    Categories=Development;
    Name=Matlab 8.01
    GenericName=Matlab 8.01
    Comment="Start Matlab 8.01"
```

## 2. libSBML

### 2.1. Install libSBML

libSBML is provided by a deb package specific for Ubuntu (and for CentOS), and also versions for several flavours of Windows and MacOSX (their home page: http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML). Guess which is the only platform whose binaries weren't compiled with MATLAB support? Linux, of course. That means you will need to compile from source (and that the deb package is therefore useless to you). To compile:

#### 2.1.1. Install dependencies

The dependency `libxml2-dev` (from software manager or from a terminal):

```
    sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

#### 2.1.2. Save yourself some time in the future

Usually, one would do `configure`, `make` and then `make install`. But this is not recommended for the same reason as installing anything that doesn't come in a pretty little package: you will loose control of which files went where, and will need to keep the source-code to be able to run `make uninstall` if you need to uninstall it later. So, install `checkinstall` and use it to replace the step `make install`, since `checkinstall` creates a package for your system that can be later uninstalled or reinstalled just as any regular packaged software (from software manager or from a terminal):

```
    sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

#### 2.1.3. Configure the compiling-process

Get LibSBML source code and extract it to some folder. From a terminal, navigate to that folder and configure the compilation:

```
    ./configure --with-matlab
```

OBS: with the `with-matlab` flag, the configure script will fail it it cannot find an executable whose filename is `matlab`. If it fails, it outputs that the `matlab` file could not be found, but the test it performs is actually both for the existence of the file and whether it is executable. So, if the file is in an NTFS partition, configure will fail even if it finds the file, but will tell you the file couldn't be found. You can enforce it to look for the executable in `/path/to/matlab/root` by passing (it will look for a `bin` folder inside that path, and for the executable inside that `bin` folder):

```
    ./configure --with-matlab=/path/to/matlab/root
```

OBS: This will install libSBML in the default location: `/usr/local/lib`. Again, it is a good idea to just let it install in its default location, but if you need to change it, you can pass the path with the flag: `--prefix=/your/installation/path`

OBS 2: You might ask why libSBML needs to find and execute matlab to be compiled with support for it: it needs to fire up MATLAB later to build MEX-files (compiled MATLAB code), so I would speculate you wouldn't be able to install libSBML after all if your MATLAB has no compiler to generate MEX-files.

#### 2.1.4. Build and install libSBML

```
    make
    checkinstall
```

**VERY IMPORTANT OBS**:

**I)** `checkinstall` asks for confirmation of the metadata of the package it is about to create. In my case, the string for the `version` field came by default as "Source" (without the quotes), which caused `checkinstall` to fail because `dpkg` (the system tool that actually builds the deb file) failed complaining the version number must start with, well, a number. So, save yourself some time and make sure the string in the `version` field starts with a number (i.e. "5.10", without the quotes obviously)

**II)** `checkinstall` asks if you want to exclude from the future package files that the `make install` command would put in your home folder and says it is a good idea to exclude them. LibSBML has a `test.xml` file that it needs to be in the `$HOME` folder later, or else it won't let you integrate with MATLAB. And even though it tells you a `test.xml` is missing, it doesn't tell you *where* that file should be or if that file was something that came with the library. I only noticed it because `checkinstall` had found a `$HOME/test.xml` reference earlier (that I excluded from the package, of course) and I had found that odd. So, save yourself some time and exclude `$HOME/test.xml` from the package generated by `checkinstall`, and then search for `test.xml` inside the source-code folder and copy it to `$HOME` as soon as libSBML finishes being installed by `checkinstall`.

### 2.2. Integrate libSBML to MATLAB

Fire up MATLAB, navigate to where the SBML MATLAB-bindings were installed in step ***2.1.5*** (in my case: `/usr/local/lib`) and run the file `installSBML.m` that should be there.

#### 2.2.1. Shared libraries problems

In my case, I had an error due to an old unresolved issue: `libstdc++.so.6` not having a reference to `GLIBCXX_3.4.15`. Turns out that MATLAB was trying to use a `libstdc++.so.6.0.13` (`libstdc++.so.6` was a symbolic link pointing to this file) that came with it in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64`, which indeed didn't have that reference (one could verify that by issuing:

```
    strings /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13 | grep GLIBC
```

). My system has a `libstdc++.so.6.0.19` located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` that has that reference, so I enforced MATLAB to use `6.0.19` one by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` properly (refer to step ***1.2***) and also by renaming the `libstdc++.so.6` that came with MATLAB to something else so it would not find it and would keep looking until it found my system's. *A friend of mine running Linux Mint didn't need to rename anything: for him, setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was enough.*

#### 2.2.2. Other problems

`installSBML.m` will fail if it doesn't find that `$HOME/test.xml` file mentioned in step ***2.1.5***, regardless of whether the library actually works. It assumes that if it could not test itself using a file that it assumes to be in `$HOME`, the user shouldn't have the option to install it anyway.

## 3. COBRA / SBML toolbox

### 3.1. Setup COBRA

In MATLAB, navigate to `<YOUR_COBRA_ROOT_FOLDER_HERE>/external/toolboxes/SBMLToolbox-4.1.0/toolbox` and run the file `install.m` there. You should have all set so it finds the MATLAB-bindings you set up in step ***2.2***.

### 3.2. MATLAB setpaths problems

I had to manually edit the file `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/toolbox/local/pathdef.m` as root to include the folder `/usr/local/lib` (where libSBML and its MATLAB-bindings are) to make that setting persistent. Every time I restarted MATLAB, its setpath had gone back to the default, no matter if I started MATLAB as root when setting its setpath via the MATLAB GUI.

### 3.3. Test

Now you have hopefully connected all the dots. Try it: in MATLAB, navigate to `<YOUR_COBRA_ROOT_FOLDER_HERE>` and issue:

```
    initCobraToolbox
    testAll
```

If you haven't got any third-party solvers installed and configured, it should pass **14** of the **19** tests, including the SBML test (`testSBML`). Now you can load SBML files into MATLAB and play with them.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to add a symbolic link from /usr/local/lib/libsbml.so.5 to the MATLAB sys folder by:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libsbml.so.5 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/sys/os/glnxa64/
```

This finally made the installation possible.
I installed using Cmake. To do this it is necessary to find the FindMatlab.cmake in the source package and insert the MATLAB path manually!

```
.............
        elseif(EXISTS "/Applications/MATLAB_R2008a.app/")
                set(MATLAB_ROOT_PATH "/Applications/MATLAB_R2008a.app/")    
            endif()
        else()
            if (EXISTS "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/")
                set(MATLAB_ROOT_PATH "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/")
            endif()
        endif()
..........
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, to resolve the shared library issue at point **2.2.1** I needed to install the package `matlab-support` (in Ubuntu repositories)